# Running django app with docker, unrecognized runserver arguments

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm having a problem with starting my django project in docker container. I have tried this in multiple ways, for example:

```
docker-compose run web python manage.py runserver
```

or just

```
docker-compose up
```

first time i have tried this i got no error, but i couldn't open the app in browser so i tried it again and then it stopped working completely.
I'm getting this error:

```
manage.py runserver: error: unrecognized arguments: python manage.py runserver
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=gitlabdumptables
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=gitlabdumptables
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
```

My Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
CMD python manage.py makemigrations
CMD python manage.py migrate
COPY . /code/
ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main process run in a Docker container is made up of two parts.  You're providing an `ENTRYPOINT` in the Dockerfile, and then the equivalent of a `CMD` with the Compose `command:` or `docker run ./manage.py ...` arguments.  When you have both an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD`, [the `CMD` gets passed as additional arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact); so in this case, you're running `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`.

For this setup I'd suggest:

- If you want to be able to override the command when you launch the container (which is useful), prefer `CMD` to `ENTRYPOINT` in your Dockerfile.  Then these command overrides will *replace* the command.
- If you have a useful default command (which you do), put it as the Dockerfile `CMD`.  You do not need to specify a Compose `command:`.

You're also trying to run migrations in a way that won't work; again, a container only runs a single process, and the last `CMD` or the startup-time override wins.  I'd use an *entrypoint wrapper script* to run migrations:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh

# Run migrations
python manage.py migrate

# Then run the main container command (passed to us as arguments)
exec "$@"
```

In your Dockerfile make sure this is `COPY`ed in (the existing `COPY` command you have will do it) and make this script be the `ENTRYPOINT` (with JSON-array syntax).

```bash
FROM python:3.10
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./ ./
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]                           # must be JSON-array form
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"] # not ENTRYPOINT
```

In your Compose file, you don't need to inject the code with `volumes:` or replace the `command:`, these are already part of your Dockerfile.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  db: { ... }
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    environment: { ... }
    depends_on:
      - db
    # but no volumes: or command:
```